# Looping in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I am given a list of 717 SKU's that I have to go through and add up the total values of Yearly Sales and Units Sold. I developed a code to search a SKU by year and receive the total amount. I was wondering If there was a way where I could loop to input a greater number of SKU's so that I don't have to go through individually SKU by SKU.

I am familiar with Loop statements but am not the best at executing them. Was wondering if there was a way to do this in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

I've tried Declaring and repeating the code but it has been inefficient.

```
DECLARE @SDate date
SET @SDate = '01/01/2018'
DECLARE @EDate date
SET @EDate = '12/31/2018'
DECLARE @Sku varchar(20)
SET @Sku = 'SN1580' 


SELECT        SUM(Amount) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = N'SN1580')
SELECT        SUM(Quantity) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = N'SN1580')

SELECT        SUM(Amount) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = N'SN0350')
SELECT        SUM(Quantity) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = N'SN0350')
```

Expect the results to give me something along the lines of

```
SN1234
Amount 1000
Sum 200

SN3456
Amount 2000
Sum 100
```

Or if there was a way to get the results in a format that would be easily exportable to excel.

Comment: Which technology is it?  Sql server or mysql it cant be both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think in terms of loops. Think in terms of sets.

This uses a table variable for the sku list, but you could use a CTE, an actual table, a `VALUE` list; anything, really, that lets SQL Server handle all of your search terms as a data set rather than as individual inputs.

```
DECLARE @SDate date = '01/01/2018'
DECLARE @EDate date = '12/31/2018'

DECLARE @Sku TABLE
(
  Sku varchar(20)
);

INSERT @Sku (Sku)
VALUES (N'SN1580'),
       (N'SN0350'); --<--Add your list here. Maybe use Excel to make the wrappers.

SELECT        
   l.No_ 
  ,SUM(l.Amount) AS Amount
  ,SUM(l.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM 
  dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line] AS l
  JOIN
   @Sku AS s
    ON s.Sku = l.No_
WHERE
  l.[Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
GROUP BY
  l.No_
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to pass multiple SKUs, you could use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @SDate date
SET @SDate = '01/01/2018'
DECLARE @EDate date
SET @EDate = '12/31/2018'

DECLARE @Skus table (SKU varchar(20);

INSERT INTO @SKUs
VALUES('SN1580'),
      ('SN0350');

SELECT SIL.[No_] AS SKU,
       SUM(SIL.Amount) AS Amount,
       SUM(SIL.Quanity) AS Quantity
FROM dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line] SIL --I recommeond against special characters (including white space) in object names
     JOIN @SKUs S ON SIL.[No_] = S.SKU
WHERE SIL.[Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
GROUP BY SIL.[No_];
```

If this is an application using this parametrised query, you may need to create a user defined table type and then use that:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SKUs AS TABLE (SKU varchar(20));
```

Microsoft's documentation covers how to use these in [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Edit, side note, if your column `[Shipment Date]` has both date and time values (and the time could be a value other than `00:00:00`) I suggest against `BETWEEN`. This is becuase any time after midnight on the last day would not be between those 2 dates. For example `2018-04-30 00:00:00.003` is not between `2018-04-01` and `2018-04-30`.

If you are do therefore have date and time values I suggest using this clause:

```
WHERE SIL.[Shipment Date] >= @SDate
  AND SIL.[Shipment Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EDate)
```

Comment: I was going to post an almost identical answer. I prefer this approach over using a large IN statement, because the query optimizer tends to have a hard time with those. All of the options in the IN get parsed as separate OR clauses, which means you end up with 700+ different branches the optimizer has to consider.

Comment: I posted a minute after you, Larnu. Not sure why I got the check mark, but you got a +1 from me for a) having nearly identical code to what I came up with and b) giving some really valuable extra pointers along with it.

Comment: OP probably has sort by newest and only tried the first answer, I imagine @EricBrandt.

Comment: Fair observation. After I saw you had beat me, I almost deleted, but really wanted to discourage looping.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it all in one query using an IN statement where you have comma separated list in your IN statement.  Depending on what SQL technology it is your syntax may be slightly different.

```
SELECT      No_ AS SKU, SUM(Amount) AS Amount, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM        dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE       ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) 
            AND (No_ IN 
                ('SN1580', 'SN0350')
            )
GROUP BY No_;
```

Or if you have your SKU's in a table you can change the IN to this:

```
            AND (No_ IN 
                (Select SKU from yourTableHere)
            )
```